# Select de la última inserción de un varchar

Tags: sql

Tengo que sacar la ultima inserción de una columna de tipo nvarchar, pero en esa columna hay inserciones de tipo date de dos formatos:
     -Uno es: 14/5/2018 1:26:05. 
     -Y el otro es: 5/14/2018 1:26:05 AM.
¿Cómo puedo puedo convertir ambos formatos al mismo formato sin borrar nada de la BD y a continuación sacar la última inserción?

Comment: La pregunta es, por qué se insertan así en la base de datos? La solución es o bien corregirlas mediante php al pedirlas para usarlas, o bien corregir los datos ANTES de insertarlos a la base de datos. Con sql no se puede cambiar el formato, una base de datos almacena información, no se encarga de ninguna lógica.

Comment: PD: Te aconsejo que desarrolles más la pregunta, pongas ejemplos, imágenes, código de lo que hayas probado, todo lo que pueda ser de utilidad para poder guiarte a buen camino, no solo para esta pregunta, si no para todas las posibles futuras preguntas, más información en [cómo formular mi pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Este es el típico problema de cuando se diseña erróneamente la base de datos, que luego tienes que dar mil vueltas para hacer cosas tan sencillas como `ORDER BY columna` si  `columna` fuera del tipo de dato que tiene que ser. Tú podrás tratar de implementar mil soluciones para **este** problema, las cuales funcionarán a veces sí, a veces no, porque tus datos no están controlados, porque admitirían valores como `40/40/-1050` (día 40, del mes 40 del año -1050)... el problema **de fondo** es siempre el mismo y la solución **definitiva** es una sola: **guardar los datos en una columna `DATETIME`**